# Textbox whose value remains same even after runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am making an application using Visual studio for windows phone / C#.
I am stuck here...
I want a text box whose value can be changed during runtime.
But when user closes the application and re runs it, the value should be there(last changed one).
here is code..

```
int k,m;
if (k <= m)
            {
                k = m+1;
                ABC.Text = k.ToString();
            }
```

i WANT abc.Text to be the text box which am looking for
Please Help
Thank you

Comment: Where do you intend to persist those values ?

Comment: its just like highscore....It can get update...but will be same forever untill its changed

Comment: What i mean if this is any parameter then you might save it to some configuration file and then load it from there on app load, there is hardly any info in the question

Comment: you have to store the textbox value in some file , and reload the value from the file. there is no other way other than storing it somewhere in memory.

Comment: @CyprUS Can you please show me how to do that as am new to this coding stuff..

Comment: @V4Vendetta : the 2 int are such that 'm' is no of seconds application is running.
And i used 'k' int to show that duration in textbox abc :)

Comment: @user1371640 : i am posting a sample code now

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the values that you want to be displayed in the textbox outside of your application's memory space since the application's memory is cleaned up after it closes. An option is store it into a file and write the value into it before the app closes. A sample code is given below :

```
 using System;
 using System.Text;
 using System.IO;

 namespace FileWriting_SW
 {
  class Program
  {
    class FileWrite
    {
        public void WriteData()
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\test.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the text which you want to write to the file");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            sw.WriteLine(str);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
      }
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           FileWrite wr = new FileWrite();
           wr.WriteData();
       }
       }
    }
```

The code and the explanation can be found at this site [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/file-handling-in-C-Sharp/) . This code is , of course , only an console application in c# . Read more on file handling and how to do it in windows-phone . Then all the pieces will fit together.

Comment: so i should put it after
  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
}

Comment: @user1371640 : you cannot use the code as it is , read what i have written , it is just a way to handle files in c# , for your application you will have to modify it as per your app . here is a link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0524d6/filehandling-in-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in **isolated storage** and store your value there.

when your application loads, retrieve and display the value.

If you don't know how to use isolated storage, watch [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/egibson/Windows-Phone-7-Jump-Start-Session-7-of-12-Advanced-Application-Development-Part-1) video.